# Private member on prototype with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, function, scope, prototype, private-members

is this possible?

We sure know how to emulate private members in javascript:

```
var Class = (function() {
    var _private;

    Class = function() {
        _private = {};
    };

    Class.prototype.set = function(name, value) {
        _private[name] = value;
    };

    Class.prototype.get = function(name) {
        return _private[name];
    };

    return Class;

})();
```

The side effect of this pattern is that when I create two instances:

```
var instanceOne = new Class();
var instanceTwo = new Class();
```

then the private property is shared between:

```
instanceOne.set('test', 'me');
instanceTwo.get('test');
```

Is there some work around for this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to have "private" members in JavaScript is to use local variables within the constructor and have anything that needs to access them defined as closures over the context of the call to the constructor, like this:

```
function Class() {
    var privateValue = 0;

    this.getPrivateValue = function() {
        return privateValue;
    };
}
Class.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    // This function doesn't have access to `privateValue`
    // except through `getPrivateValue`, even though
    // it's accessible as a member of the instance
};
```

This has been described by many, probably most famously [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html).

Note that this has the repercussion that *each instance* of `Class` gets its *own* copy of the `getPrivateValue` function, because each is a closure over a different call to the constructor (which is why it works). (This doesn't mean all the *code* of the function is duplicated, however; at least some engines — Google's V8 engine, used in Chrome and elsewhere for instance — allow the same *code* to be shared by multiple function objects which have different associated contexts.)

(Side note: I haven't used the name `private` because it's a reserved word. In ES3, it was a "future reserved word;" in ES5, it's only one in strict mode; [details](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2).)

I've used a simple variable above rather than an object to avoid making things look more complex than they are. Here's the way the would apply to your example:

```
function Class() {
    var privateData = {};

    this.get = function(name) {
        return privateData[name];
    };

    this.set = function(name, value) {
        privateData[name] = value;
    };
}
```

Or if you still want to *also* have class-wide private data shared across instances:

```
var Class = function() {
    var dataSharedAmongstInstances;

    function Class() {
        var privateDataForEachInstance = {};

        this.get = function(name) {
            return privateDataForEachInstance[name];
        };

        this.set = function(name, value) {
            privateDataForEachInstance[name] = value;
        };
    }

    return Class;
})();
```

Comment: The more common way, also used in python, is underscore prefixing. People should know that the functions created in constructor are not static, they are unique objects per each function created for every instance.

Comment: @Esailija: Underscore prefixing doesn't create private members. (I know **you** know this, but for anyone lurking...) It creates public members with names starting with underscores, full stop. *Treating* them as private is entirely something someone does in the code by convention, nothing more. And yes, a lot of people do it. But because the privacy isn't enforced, people will break the rule. In fact, I've never worked with a significant codebase using that rule where someone *didn't* break it. But that statement is cheating a bit, I've only worked on a couple of projects using that rule. ;-)

Comment: Well, this doesn't create private members either, they are variables. They are only treated as members but you cannot do any of the stuff with them that real object properties support

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is it also possible to define the functions outside of the constructor?

Comment: If you really need enforced privacy, it's better to use some other language that compiles to javascript, such as typescript, dart or whatever.

Comment: @Esailija: Re "private variables" vs. "private members," that's quite true, but entirely a semantic point. And I disagree about using other languages instead of JavaScript, but that's a personal decision.

Comment: @kyogron: Not if you want truly private per-instance data, no, because the mechanism is based on those functions being closures over the context of the call to the constructor. Probably worth mentioning that true private members are on the way for JavaScript (the next spec) -- and they're being done in a brilliantly JavaScript-y way. :-)

Comment: @Esailija I have just compiled down a class with private variable in a typescript down to javascript and mentioned that the privacy (like the type stuff) is just in typescript itself. The final compiled code does not support this future

Comment: @kyogron Well yeah, privacy is a compiler enforced thing. If you have a working program, modify all private to public, it will still work exactly the same.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay I will keep your method in mind until someday we harmony flies to our heart :)

Comment: To expose my intention: I would like to expose my api someday to third party (anonymous) developers which could hack into the main app

Comment: @kyogron: The idea isn't original with me. It's been described by many people, most famously [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) (I should have linked to that originally, and now have). If you haven't read Crockford, I recommend doing so. Take what he says with a grain of salt (he tends to state his opinions as though they were facts), and come to your own conclusions, but he makes good points in many cases and certainly makes one think.